# Speed up GeoJSON clustering and rendering?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, rendering

I am rendering 10,000 points with Leaflet's markercluster library.

I fetch these 10k points from our server. This takes about 700ms. It takes Leaflet about 3 seconds to cluster these points and display them on our map. How can I speed up this clustering and rendering?

Here is a minimal example of my leaflet code. We are using the [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) framework.

```js
createMapWithLeafletAndMapTiler() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  var satelliteTilesLayer = L.tileLayer(MAPTILER_SATELLITE_URL, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 2
  });
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  var streetTilesLayer = L.tileLayer(MAPTILER_STREETS_URL, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 2,
    attribution: MAPBOX_ATTRIBUTION
  });
  var baseMaps = {
    Satellite: satelliteTilesLayer,
    Streets: streetTilesLayer
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  this.myMap = L.map("leafletMapId", {
    center: [-50.99404, 39.75621],
    zoom: 5,
    layers: [streetTilesLayer]
  }).setView([39.75621, -104.99404], 3);

  this.markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

  L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(this.myMap);

  this.getGeoJsonFromServer();
}

async getGeoJsonFromServer() {
  var timeBeforeFetch = new Date();
  var bounds = this.myMap.getBounds();
  this.swLat = bounds._southWest.lat;
  this.swLng = bounds._southWest.lng;
  this.neLat = bounds._northEast.lat;
  this.neLng = bounds._northEast.lng;
  axios
    .get("/maps/" + this.list_id, {
      params: {
        q: this.searchTerms,
        swLat: this.swLat,
        swLng: this.swLng,
        neLat: this.neLat,
        neLng: this.neLng
      },
      headers: { "Content-Encoding": "gzip" }
    })
    .then(
      response => {
        f (!response.data.exceedsLimit) {
          this.geoJsonObject = response.data.geoJson;
          this.geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(this.geoJsonObject, {
          });
          this.markers.addLayer(this.geoJsonLayer);
          this.myMap.addLayer(this.markers);
        }
      },
      error => {
        store.setErrorMessage("Network error searching list", error);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are doing the clustering. Your code seems to be adding the entire GeoJSON with all the Individual points on the map.

Comment: Thank you, @DevdattaTengshe I had left out an important line in my example. Just edited the post.

Comment: Are you using bounds(current extent) to limit the result ?

Comment: Example from plugin for 10.000 markers work just fine: https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.10000.html. Check with profiler what's happening in your case.

Comment: Try with `chunkedLoading: true` option for `L.markerClusterGroup`.

Comment: One other thing that is different in the example cited above. Individual markers are added one by one, not through hugh GeoJSON object. Maybe GeoJSON processing is slowing things down.

Comment: In my code, I replaced the geojson object with an array of arrays, just like the leaflet markercluster's 10,000 markers example. I set chunkedLoading to true and used bounds to limit the result. The page still takes just as long to render. I don't understand how the example renders so quickly.

Comment: I was able to make my page renders more quickly. My website is written in the vue.js framework. I removed the component variables this.markers and this.myMap and replaced them with ordinary javascript variables.

Comment: For some reason, now that the functions do not need to reference and/or update component variables, the clusters render 1 to 2 seconds faster. Instead of 2.5 seconds, the fetch, clustering and rendering all take about 0.5 seconds now. I wonder why using vue.js component variables slows things down. Any ideas? I did notice that when I was using component variables, my browser console printed out this error message a few times: [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 207ms. Now that I removed the component variables, the console prints this error message only once.

Comment: Without knowing implementation architecture of vue.js it's impossible to say what is the reason for slow behavior. I noticed the following statement on their site: "Blazing Fast Virtual DOM". Whatever this Virtual DOM is, it might be the culprit. The most you can do is to use browser debugger profiler to see where it things get slowed down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use current map extent and limit the result from your service. 
and you can add a map extent change listener to bring only that data which is falling under that extent.

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
   var bounds = map.getBounds(); //use this bounds
});
```